# Remove special characters from XML via XSLT only for specific tags

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

I am having a certian issue with special characters in my XML.
Bascially I am splitting up an xml into multiple xmls using Xalan Processor.

When splitting the documents up I am using their value of the name tag as the name of the file generated. The problem is that the name contains characters that arent recognized by the XML processor like ™ (TM) and ® (R). I want to remove those characters ONLY when naming the files.

```
<xsl:template match="products">
    <redirect:write select="concat('..\\xml\\product\\en\\',translate(string(name),'&lt;/&gt; ',''),'.xml')">
```

The above is the XSL code I have writter to split the XML into multlpe XMLs. As you can see I am using hte translate method to subtitute '/','<','>'  with '' from the name. I was hoping I could do the same with ™ (TM) and ® (R) but it doesnt seem to work.
Please advice me how I would be able to do that.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I don't have Xalan, but with 8 other XSLT processors this thransformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&lt;/&gt;™®', '')"/>
   ===================
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&lt;/&gt;&#x2122;&#xAE;', '')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document:**

```
<t>XXX™ My Trademark®</t>
```

**produces the wanted result:**

```
XXX My Trademark
   ===================
   XXX My Trademark
```

**I suggest that you try to use one of the two expressions above** -- at least the second may work successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Following Dimitre answer, I think that if you are not sure about wich special character could be in `name`, maybe you should keep what you consider legal document's name characters.

As example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,
                                   translate(.,
                                             'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ',
                                             ''),
                                   '')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With input:

```
<t>XXX™ My > Trademark®</t>
```

Result:

```
XXX My  Trademark
```