# Remove special characters from XmlCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt, encoding, special-characters

I'm taking a `DataSet`, loading it into an `XmlDocument`, transforming it with an XSLT file and trying to remove special characters from my output file.

Abbreviated code:

```
DataSet ds = GetData(); //queries database
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(ds.GetXml());

XslCompiledTransform trans = new XmlCompiledTransform();
trans.Load("myTemplate.xslt");

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("C:\output.xml", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-885901"));

trans.Transform(doc, null, writer);
writer.Close();
```

XSLT Header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
```

I thought it just had to do with the Encoding, which is why I put the `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` on there, though I may have the wrong one.  Specifically, I need to remove characters like ® from the output.  If it's not the encoding, then is there any way I can strip these characters out?

Comment: The wanted encoding of the output of the transformation is specified in the `xsl:output` directive: `<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1"/>` . This has nothing to do with the `encoding` pseude-attribute of the XML declaration of the stylesheet XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently switching the encoding isn't the way to go, because this character exists in ISO-8859-1 so it still shows up.  Switching to a basic encoding like ASCII just ended up changing those symbols it can't recognize to question marks.

My solution is like Jhigs, but I didn't want to loop through the `DataSet` rows, manually applying a regex filter on things.  I used the answer to this question:

[Remove special characters from XML via XSLT only for specific tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205763/remove-special-characters-from-xml-via-xslt-only-for-specific-tags)

```
<Description>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(DESC, '&lt;/&gt;&#x2122;&#xAE;', '')" />
</Description>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using    regex. this will remove all of the special characters

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string specialCharacters)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("(?:[^a-z0-9 ]|(?<=['\"])s)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |  RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return regex.Replace(specialCharacters, String.Empty);
}
```

then just adjust your code so you can retain some of the special character you need